# Event triggers multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("input[type='color']").on("change blur", function() {
    alert("changed");
});
```

This also applies to other elements, but this is a good example. When using a colour input type on some browsers it triggers on 'change' but not on 'blur', on some it triggers on 'blur', but not on 'change' and some it triggers on both.

Is there a good method to ensure it only triggers once?

I'm mainly talking about various mobile browsers here.

Comment: I didn't test it or anything, but have you tried putting in a stop Propagation or stopImmediatePropagation in?

Comment: Technically `change` should be the correct event to listen for.

Comment: Why is it a problem if both events occur?

Comment: 'change' is the correct one, but iOS 5 (not 6, which works) and BlackBerry PlayBook Tablet OS (tested v2) won't trigger on 'change' but they do trigger on 'blur' (not thoroughly tested others either). There are also all sorts of problems with the date/time input types, but not any more with Jack's solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a specialized version of `.one()` that will rebind the event handlers after the first event has been handled. It does this in a wrapper so that the event handler code itself doesn't have to be changed.

```
$.fn.one_rebind = function(events, listener) {
  return this.one(events, function fn() {
    var $self = $(this).unbind(events);

    listener.apply(this, arguments);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $self.one(events, fn);
    }, 0);
  });
};

$('input[type=color]').one_rebind('change blur', function(evt) {
  document.getElementById('debug').innerText += ' ' + evt.type;
});
```

Although tested, your mileage may vary :)

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ocisow/3/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Perfect. If I was trusted to, I would up-vote. This is the best answer by a mile.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the `.one()` event handler instead of `.on()` http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: This is definitely the way to go about it.

Comment: You still need to reattach the event handlers at some point and that process is non-trivial; an example implementation can be seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14846526/1338292).

Answer (score 0):

Start your function with this:

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
if( arguments.callee.lastcalled > now-250) return false;
arguments.callee.lastcalled = now;
```

What this does is limit the function from being called more than once every 250 milliseconds (which is usually enough without risking missing actual duplicates)

Comment: Some explanation would be nice too ;-)

Comment: @Jack Basically the snipped above prevents the function from being called less that 250ms after it was last called.

Comment: `arguments.callee` is being deprecated.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff And how exactly are you supposed to refer to the current function?

Comment: By name. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee

Comment: If you refer to it by name, then it's not "anonymous", is it?

Comment: @ThinkingStiff It's not so much deprecated as it's disallowed in strict mode.